# SQL COUNT(DISTINCT(field1)) GROUP BY MAX(filed2)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table like

```
name  num_try

John     2
John     1
Mike     3
Mike     2
Linda    2
```

And I want to know count distinct names group by `MAX(num_try)`.

Desired result should look like

```
MAX(num_try)  COUNT(DISTINCT(names))
     2            2
     3            1
```

Can you help me with this query?

Comment: that actually does not make much sense.. can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to know distinct count of names group by their  MAX(num_try)

Comment: I see... nice... one sec

Comment: see edited answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select max_num_try, count(*) from 
(
   select name, max(num_try) as max_num_try
   from table1
   group by name
) a
group by max_num_try
order by max_num_try desc
```